# UISegmentedcontrol to switch views in UITabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to switch between multiple different views using a `UISegmentedControl`. I found a really good example to do this in:
http://redartisan.com/2010/6/27/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited

However, I need to use a `UITabbarController` in my app. So the navigation controller is not available for me in the app delegate. Is there any other way to switch views in a `UITabbarController` using `UISegmentedControl`?

Answer (score 2):

First, consider whether you really want to do this. UITabBarController already gives you the ability to switch views, using the tab bar.

If you really want to do this for some reason, UITabBarController has properties `viewControllers` and `selectedViewController` that should allow you to do something like what is described in that article.

Comment: I understand that UITabBarController provides the ability to switch views, However I am looking to offer sublevels inside each tab bar item.

Comment: If that's what you're doing, why can't you use the UINavigationController solution you already have as the view controller inside each tab?

Comment: That tutorial seems to use a  NSObject as the SegmentsController. Since it is not a UIView I'm not sure if Mark can use it as a tabbar view.